# shopify schema with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shopify

Wondering how to mount a vue js app on schema sections?
There is the {% javascript %} tag can be used to include JavasScript for a section!
but I can't mount a vue js app insid it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example. very appreciated

Comment: `{% javascript %}

if (document.querySelector('#vo')) {

var vm = new Vue({
    data() {
        return {
           
            open: 'yes'
         

        }
    },
  }).mount('#vo')


}
{% endjavascript %}`

Comment: ​ TypeError: Vue is not a constructor
    at scripts.js:14
    at scripts.js:29
    at scripts.js:31